# How to declare computed values in SFC/Composition in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use `computed` fields in VueJs.

Previously it was achievable with:

```js
{
  props: {
    left: 5,
    right: 100,
  },
  computed: {
    width: () {return this.right.value - this.left.value};
  }
}
```

But with the new SFC/Composition syntax how do I do it?

```html
<script setup>
defineProps({left: 5, right: 100});

defineComputed(  //??
)
</script>
```

I've read this link but it doesn't explain it:
https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0040-script-setup.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the new setup syntax, you use [`computed`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#computed-values) to create a computed property:

```js
import { computed } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({left: 5, right: 100});
const width = computed(() => props.right - props.left);
```